# Determining a PHP object's name

Tags: php, oop, object

In Java (well, Android's version at least) all objects have a `getClass()` method which returns the object's class and you can then call `getSimpleName()` to get the human-readable name of the object. This is great for logging. I'd like to be able to do something similar in a PHP program I've been working on. Is there any way to find out what type of object "this" is?

Comment: in Java `getClass()` is a method on the class `Object`, the root of the object inheritance hierarchy.  So it's there even if you aren't on Android. :)

Comment: I assumed that was probably the case, but I haven't done any Java work outside of Android so I wasn't certain (and was too lazy to look it up).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
return get_class($this);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this php.net man page may have the answers your looking for:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php