# How to get the object or class name?

Tags: php, arrays, object

Right now, I have this code where `$obj_arr` maybe contain array and an object.

```
$obj_temp = array ($obj_identity, $arr_user, $obj_locale, $arr_query); 

foreach ($obj_temp as $maybe_arr) {
        if (is_array($maybe_arr)) :
            $name = (string) key($maybe_arr);
        if (is_object($maybe_arr)) :    
            ???? // how to retrieve a class name ?
        endif;  

        $obj_arr[$name] = $maybe_arr;

}



obj_will_be_extract($obj_arr);
```

```
function obj_will_be_extract($obj_arr) {
    extract($obj_arr);

    //Do the rest

}
```

I need to create an array consist of combination of objects and arrays. Cause I need to extract it, then how to get an object name?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976160/determining-a-php-objects-name

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use [`get_class`](http://php.net/get_class) to get the class name of an object.

Answer (score 11):

Since PHP 5.5 you can use  `MyAction::class` statement, so you can get a class name without class initialization

Comment: I recently came across this by an accident. It doesn't seem to be documented anywhere. Have you seen any official information on this?